# Install php on windows server2008r2

Tags: php, cacti

I am going to install cacti on windows server 2008R2,but at the first i should install PHP 
I downloaded VC11 x64 Non-THread Safe and I done all of the instructions in cacti's site 
http://docs.cacti.net/manual:088:1_installation.2_install_windows.1_configure_php
but when in cmd promt i write php -m ,i have an error that says "the program can not start because MSVCR.dll is missing from your computer"
plz,what should i do?

Comment: Did you tried just google your error message? https://www.google.hu/search?num=100&q=%22the+program+can%27t+start+because+MSVCR.dll+is+missing+from+your+computer&spell=1&sa=X&ei=mLKaVLizHoTNygOZq4C4Cw&ved=0CBoQvwUoAA&biw=1280&bih=816

Comment: No,I am going to try